# How to make camera focus only on face in OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, roi

I want camera to focus only on object or face using haar-classifiers (ex: face classifier or smile classifiers) remaining part of the image must be hidden or kind of blurred. I created haar classifiers for smile detection.

I want to focus only on face for my project to detect yawning.

Comment: skin color extraction using YCrCb color channel which will return you skin and you can eliminated background.

Comment: Upvote and mark it as answer so that it would be helpful for other people

Comment: How can I up vote an comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

skin color extraction using YCrCb color channel which will return you skin and you can eliminated background.
See this http://spottrlabs.blogspot.in/2012/01/super-simple-skin-detector-in-opencv.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZk9k9azonw